# Which protocol (UDP or TCP) to use in streaming images wirelessly

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, point-clouds

Our project involves streaming captured pointCloud images from Xtion Pro Live to be transmitted wirelessly from a raspberry pi to a laptop. We propose to use UDP over TCP since UDP is faster than TCP. However, we also wanted to let the raspberry pi detect if it has lost its connection to the laptop. But since UDP is connectionless, here are the solutions that I can think of:

1.) Use TCP for detecting connection and UDP for streaming pointCloud
2.) Use UDP for streaming PointCloud and in the raspberry pi, it has to receive a frame from the laptop within a time window which this should serve as the detection for connection.
3.) Use TCP.

What should I use?

Comment: If it isn't critical that the laptop receive the images as fast as possible, use TCP.

Comment: I doubt the timing of the transmission will matter here. And if you count in the effort needed (a *lot*) to code a surrounding protocol built on UDP to have connections and other safety features already in TCP, then there I don't see a reason for it at all.

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg says, I also doubt it. Do you have some actual profiling data indicating that TCP will be too slow in your application?

Comment: TCP looks like the best option for your case, even without the detecting connection problem. There is no need to remove latency apparently.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We will try TCP first and we hope everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

TCP, would be the most pragmatic option. Look how many images we receive on a single web page - that's all sent using TCP. There would be a lot more work required than detecting dead peers if you were to use UDP - you would also have to deal with dropped and duplicate packets, congestion control...